# Problem with my rig, the feet stick to the ground

Tags: rigging

I'm a beginner and I'm following a tutorial but
the 3D person I try to rig has his feet stick to the ground and deform them.
What should I do ?
The project : https://pasteall.org/blend/55639e03aefb4f9fa2b227da6732c238
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the bones called *Bone.033.L* and *Bone.033.R* and enable their *Deform* option (or assign these parts to the feet bones):

[image]

Actually you must have enabled the *Deform* option when you've parented, then you must have disabled it, it would have been better not to enable in the first place so that it was not taken into account during the parenting, *IK* controllers are not supposed to deform the mesh.

So it would be more logical to keep the *Deform* option disabled and assign this part to the foot bone.